# How can I use a dynamic attribute for route generation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my model I have this custom method:

```
def encoded_id
    "foo#{self.id.to_s}"
end
```

Now, upon calling `mymodel_path(myobject)` I would like the method mymodel_path to receive encoded_id as part of the attributes (eg. `{id: 123, bar: 'bar', encoded_id: 'foo123'}`).

**How can this be achieved *without* having to specify it on the method call itself?**

Answer (score 1):

Look for something like http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

As it follows, you can override `to_param` method in your model, like:

```
def to_param
  # some other value
end
```

Basicaly it is called when you pass object to url helper. Helper calls .to_param on model and passes it to generated url params

Comment: The return value of `to_param` is now being encoded, causing slashes `/` to be converted to `%2F`. This renders `to_params` unusable for that case, as it would generate `bar%2Ffoo123` instead of `bar/foo123`. Further details on the issue are outlined in the last few comments of https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14636#issuecomment-52625134 but the poster never got a final answer.

Comment: This is a link-only answer, which will render useless if the link goes down.

Comment: @dgilperez, hey, just mention, this is link to apidock.com, which is up and running for years. It is not someones standalone blog. If apidock will go down, tons of rubyists will not be able to write code :-D

Comment: Hey man, it's not me, it's the SO policy: http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans and http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=link+only+answer

Answer (score 0):

You should create a helper method that does this for you.

for your example: `mymodel_path(myobject)`, the helper `mymodel_path()` is not a model method but a url helper. If you don't like its functionality you should write another url helper.

```
def my_model_path_with_encoded_thing(model)
  mymodel_path({
    id: model.id, 
    bar: model.bar, 
    encoded_id: model.encoded_id
  }) if model.persisted?
end
```

If you really want to stay with `mymodel_path(object)` you could mess with params but it would break for nested routes and trying to pass normal params to the url helper:

```
def to_param
  "#{self.id}?foo=#{self.foo}&encoded_id=#{self.encoded_id}"
end
```